# Does Mouse's comment indicate that Smith is becoming human?

Tags: the-matrix

When Mouse is talking to Neo, he says

> To deny our own impulses, is to deny the very thing that makes us human

The only time that comment ever stuck out to me within the film series was when Smith confesses to Morpheus that he has a desire to be free and he hates the Matrix.

Smith has impulses. Was the comment meant to signify the growth of machines developing just like humans do?

I personally do not think it's just solely about sexual desires; *the woman in the red dress* is the topic of conversation but I think the comment represented a lot more.

Smith talks about smelling, tasting, etc probably not a literal occurrence but these are all human things.

Comment: Erm. Yes? Smith is becoming emotional. That's the core of his inappropriate actions.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @CyberClaw The question appears to be about the symbolism and wider significance of the quoted remark in the film, beyond its immediate context in the conversation.

Comment: Such a generic quote can draw many parallels. Neo becomes more robot like, calmer along the series as he embraces the role of the one. Other rebels see him as inhuman even. Likewise, Smith becomes more impulsive as a direct opposite to Neo. We see this expanded to extremes in the sequels, but you can already see it in the 1st movie. The quote is directed at Neo, and can as easily be in a way to make him ponder how much humanity he is willing to give up. Smith's path is just a consequence of being the direct opposite of Neo. So if the quote has any significance it is to Neo, not Smith.

Comment: Tempted to post an answer that just says: "Yes"